# Spring MVC: Receive XML data and Send String message back

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to collect all the form data and send it as a XML to Controller. This XML will further be sent to back end which will take care of it.
There is no need to marshal this XML into an Object.After receiving this XML I just need to send a `String success` message back.

 It is **half working**. I am able to receive XML message from UI page and able to print it on console. But when I just send success message back UI ajax call receives 
**`No conversion from text to application/xml`**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes={"application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml","text/plain"})
        @ResponseBody public String handleSave(@RequestBody String formData)
        {
            System.out.println("comes here");
            System.out.println(formData);
return "Success";

    } 

$('form').submit(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        processData: false,
                        data: collectFormData1(),

                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type":"application/xml"
                        },
                        dataType: 'application/xml',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('Success:'+data)
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log('jqXHR:'+jqXHR+'\n'+'textStatus:'+'\n'+textStatus+'errorThrown::'+errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
```

Comment: Do you know if your Spring MVC config is using `org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter` as one of its `HttpMessageConverter`s? Note that `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` will use it by default if none are explicitly configured.

You also might want to try setting the `Content-Type` of the response to `text/plain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove dataType: 'application/xml' from jquery code.

As mentioned in documentation: DataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Do I need to remove `headers: {
                            "Content-Type":"application/xml"
                        }` too?

Comment: No. It is header of request to server. Not sure, but you can try to remove it if you remove consumes={"application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml","text/plain"} line from @RequestMapping